# React's new use() hook falls into infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load data for a client component. I can't use `await/async` as specified by React's RFC about `use()` hook. Thus I need to use `use()` hook.

However, it goes into infinite loop.

Here's my code:

```
import { use } from 'react'

const Component = () => {

    const response = use(fetch('some_url'))
    const data = use(response.json())

    return <div>{data}</div>
}
```

Based on my intuition, I tried to use a callback inside the `use()` hook, as we do for `useEffect()`:

```
const response = use(() => fetch('use_url'), [])
```

But it complained that an invalid parameter is passed into the `use()` hook.

I can't find anyting online. What should I do? What have I done wrong?

Comment: **use** function is not export by react library. Please re-edit your question clearly.

Comment: As i know, `use` function as an await-like syntax, accept only one promise parameter.  [https://github.com/acdlite/rfcs/blob/first-class-promises/text/0000-first-class-support-for-promises.md#example-use-in-client-components-and-hooks](https://github.com/acdlite/rfcs/blob/first-class-promises/text/0000-first-class-support-for-promises.md#example-use-in-client-components-and-hooks)

Comment: @YinPeng.Wei, then from where should I import it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to "stabilize" the return of `fetch`. You could memoize it

```js
const Component = () => {
  const fetchPromise = React.useMemo(() => fetch('some_url').then(r => r.json()), [])
  const data = use(fetchPromise);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Made no difference. Still loops.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just wanna memorized `use` result.

```
const response = useMemo(() => use(use(fetch('some_url')).json()), ['some_deps'])
```